# Is it possible to force a remote desktop computer to login as a specific user?

Tags: remote

We are in a situation where users forget their domain password for local desktop access. We have a procedure where we contact their manager before resetting the password in order to avoid human engineering. However, sometimes the user needs their password reset when the manager is unavailable, usually at 5 AM and the manager does not start until 9 AM.

One thought we had was to remotely login their computer for them, if this is possible in Windows. Our thought is that if they are already in the facility and at their normal computer then we can allow them to work until they log out. Once they logout they will need to have the password reset.

Unfortunately we do not know if this is possible, and if it is how to search for it since the keywords are generic and mean many different things.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question. You want to remotely connect to the computer and log the user in? So long as you know their password why would this not be possible?

Comment: Not exactly what we would like to do is to force the computer to login on the console as a specific user. Something similar to the ability to remotely shutdown/reboot a computer using the shutdown /m /r \\comuter-name

Comment: You can restrict each user to a single computer but logging in without a password means *zero security*.

Comment: Really all I think you need to do is what you do now, but do not communicate the new password to them until an approval is received. For example, reset the password of the account, use your remote control tool to connect to the console of their endpoint, logon using their credentials, then let them take over. Basically a 100% procedure change.

Comment: As far as I am aware, Microsoft does not provide a tool which allows us to remotely access the desktop without the user being logged in. RDP, does not allow shared access to the desktop as far as I know. Products such as Teamviewer, VNC & the like require their product be installed. This introduces cost, complexity and malware vectors.